# jQuery add/remove items and reset counter

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following piece of code:

```
var counter = $("#myTable tbody").children().length;
```

Remove function:

```
$(document).on('click', 'a.remove', function() {
    if(counter == 1) {
        return false;
    }

    $(this).closest('tr').fadeOut().remove();
    counter--;
});
```

Add Function:

```
$('#add').on('click', function() {
  if (counter > 10) {
      return false;
  }
  counter++;
  var newTr = $('<tr data-id="' + counter + '"></tr>');

  newTr.html(
      '<td><i class="icon reorder"></i></td>\
      <td><small>' + counter + '.</span></td>\
      <td> <input type = "text" name = "price[]" data-id = "' + counter + '"></td>\
      <td><a class="remove"><i class="icon delete"></i></a></td>\
      ');
  });
```

When removing item on click, I would like to reset counter, so the value between `<small></small>` is restored in sequence starting at 1.

Comment: Can describe _"restored in sequence starting at 1"_ ? What is expected result ?

Comment: try to put your code on jsfiddle, and let us know what is the expected result so we can help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like you need, after remove an item, loop through all `tr` and setup `small text` and `input data-id` again with the new value

```
$(document).on('click', 'a.remove', function() {
    if(counter == 1) {
        return false;
    }

    $(this).closest('tr').fadeOut().remove();

    counter = 0;

    $("#myTable tbody").children().each(function(){
        counter++;
        $(this)
            .find("small").text( counter )
            .end()
            .find("input").attr( "data-id", counter );
    });
});
```